# Firebase creating user from the Firebase console?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase. actually, I'm developing an Android app where the admin creates a username and password for the user from the server and whereas the user(from application logins with the same username and password created by the admin), is that possible if yes please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using login system trough mail + password. You can add users manually here:
[image: Firebese Console: user management page - screenshot]

Comment: sorry screenshot is in french, but the UI does not change

Comment: Great answer! In case you want to change the language for a screenshot next time, add `?hl=en` to the end of your URL. :-)

Comment: thank you soo much :) do you know how can i implement this using android ?

Comment: You can use their library firebaseui  authentication for Android. It's a project on github. There is also a sample app. It's quite straightforward to implement. You can find it here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android